# How do I convert to date data_type after concatenating?

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a query where I am concatenating month and year and saving it as MY, which converts it to string. Need help converting to date data_type from string after concatenating.

```
select concat (month(date),'-', year(date)) as MY, post_evar10, device_type, sum(pageviews) as pageviews, count(distinct uniquevisitors) as uniquevisitors
from temp.MS_Adobe_Discover1
group by MY, post_evar10, device_type
order by MY asc;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to convert to a date in Sparksql:

```
select to_date(concat(year(date), '-', month(date), '-01')) as yyyymmdd,
       post_evar10, device_type,
       sum(pageviews) as pageviews, count(distinct uniquevisitors) as uniquevisitors
from temp.MS_Adobe_Discover1
group by yyyymmdd, post_evar10, device_type
order by yyyymmdd asc;
```

Comment: now the date is coming as 2018-10-01, I just want to show 2018-10 that is month and year.

Comment: @NewCode . . . "Need help converting to date data_type".  This is your question and what this answer does.  If you want a string in YYYY-MM format, you have that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no date type format like "2019-10" or "10-2019".

We can get this string from date type but can not convert the string from  "2019-10" or "10-2019" to date data type. It will give the error:

[image]

If we want to do this convert, we must add a 'DD' for the string like Gordon showed for you.

Or please not convert it to date data type, still using the varchar data type. A little difference from your query:

```
select concat (year(date),'-', month(date)) as MY, post_evar10, device_type, sum(pageviews) as pageviews, count(distinct uniquevisitors) as uniquevisitors
from temp.MS_Adobe_Discover1
group by MY, post_evar10, device_type
order by MY asc;
```

Hope this helps.